# Asp .Net LINQ to SQL Databinding, do a "lookup" without a lookup table?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, data-binding, lookup

Say I have an Employee table. Each Employee has a unique id. One of the columns in the table is ManagerId, which corresponds to another Employee. When binding an Employee's data to a GridView, I want to display the Manager's name, not their Id. If I had a lookup table for Mangers I could just do `<%# Eval("lu_Managers.ManagerName") %>`, but I don't have such a table, nor do I want to make one/keep track of it/update it everytime a new manager is added or removed.

Currently in the OnRowDataBound I call `e.Row.Cells[1].Text = getFullNameFromEmployeeId(Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[1].Text));` which seems fairly messy to me.

Is there a way to do this without using the codebehind? Or would that be less efficient than what I have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the Employee table again for the manager

```
SELECT 
  Employee.*,
  Manager.FirstName As ManagerName
FROM
  tblEmployee As Employee
  JOIN tblEmployee As Manager
    ON Employee.ManagerID = Manager.pkEmployeeID
```

**EDIT:**
Which can be easily translated into LINQ:

```
var q = 
 from employee in db.tblEmployee
 join manager in db.tblEmployee
   on employee.ManagerID equals manager.pkEmployeeID
 select new
 {
   Employee = employee,
   ManagerName = manager.FirstName
 };
```

Comment: I'dd upvote if it wasn't an SQL Example for a LINQ question (-: Its the right answer...

Comment: That might work if I where using straightup SQL, but I'm using LINQ to SQL DataContexts, and thus not doing any SELECTs.

Comment: Linq or SQL, almost the same ;-)

Comment: Ah, misunderstanding. So this isn't something that can be done without using the codebehind, aka I can't do this from within the aspx file?

Comment: You set the datasource of the grid the the query specified, this can be done in codebehind or in the ASPX page (Using the LinqDataSource control)

Comment: Righteous. I was unaware one could do that. Exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if there a unary relationship setup?  If a relationship, Employee would have an Employee property that points to that manager, so you could reference with Employee.EmployeeName.  Otherwise, if no explicit navigation property, you would have to use a query from code-behind.

HTH.

Comment: I have created a FK from Employee.ManagerID to Employee.EmployeeId(the PK). But how do I use that within my Eval statement? <%# Eval("ManagerID.FirstName") %> returns an error, which makes sense, as the Int32 "ManagerID" has no "FirstName" property.

Comment: Use the new Manager property (or whatever SQLMETAL called it)

Comment: Yes, there should be a Manager or Employee property.